# VisualStateManager.GoToState useTransitions Ignored in custom control UWP

Tags: animation, uwp, custom-controls, windows-10-universal, visualstatemanager

I've created a custom control which inherits from `contentControl` . The control uses `PlaneProjection.RotationX` animation while changing from open to close and vice versa.

I want the control initial state to be in closed state. When the app launched the transition from open to close is shown even though I set `changeVisualState(false)`.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
public sealed class FlipPanel : ContentControl
{
    private VisualState collapsedState;
    private FrameworkElement contentElement;

    public FlipPanel()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(FlipPanel);
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(FlipPanel), new PropertyMetadata(false, onIsOpenChanged));

    private static void onIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        FlipPanel flipPanel = d as FlipPanel;
        flipPanel.changeVisualState(true);
    }

    private void changeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(IsOpen.ToString());
        if (IsOpen)
        {
            if (contentElement != null)
            {
                contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Opening", useTransitions);
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Closing", useTransitions);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        contentElement = (FrameworkElement)GetTemplateChild("Content");

        if (contentElement != null)
        {
            collapsedState = (VisualState)GetTemplateChild("Closing");

            if ((collapsedState != null) && (collapsedState.Storyboard != null))
            {
                collapsedState.Storyboard.Completed += (object sender, object e) =>
                {
                    contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                };
            }

            changeVisualState(false);
        }         
    }
}
```

and my `Style`

```
<Style TargetType="local:FlipPanel" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:FlipPanel">
                <Grid>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opening">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closing">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="90"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content">
                                <ContentPresenter.Projection>
                                    <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationX="0.5"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Projection>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you make the `Content` Collapsed in the `Completed` event of the storyboard and then you set `changeVisualState(false);`, it will do nothing since the "closing" storyboard is completed.

I modified your code of `OnApplyTemplate` like this and it works:

```cs
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    contentElement = (FrameworkElement)GetTemplateChild("Content");
    if (contentElement != null)
    {
        if (!IsOpen)
            contentElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            changeVisualState(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. So setting `useTransitions` to `false` in a `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method will still run the animation?

Comment: @PutraKg, I didn't mean that, when you set useTransitions to false in `OnApplyTemplate()`, the animation is done, so it doesn't work...